# Notion of submodel relation

Tags: logic, definition, relations, model-theory

There is no definition of the essential notion of substructure (=submodel) in Shelah's introduction E56 to AEC, 1st Volume.
Could someone please define this for me?
I think that
$$M \subseteq N$$ ($M$ is a submodel of $N$)
iff

> 1. $M$ is a subset of $N$,
> 2. all constants $c$ from $N$ are in $M$,
>
> 3.$f(M^n)\in M$ for all $n$-ary function symbols $f$,
>
> 4. **I don't know what for relation symbols**...And yet, must it be the case $M\neq \emptyset$ ?

Comment: Just the restriction?

Comment: Note that the notion of "structure" here is the same as the notion of "structure" in first-order logic. The notion of "substructure" is also the same.

Comment: What are you doing reading about AECs from Shelah before you know the definition of substructures/submodels? I *cannot recommend strongly enough* that you start by learning model theory from one of the excellent textbooks on the subject (e.g. Hodges or Marker) before you dive in to anything about AECs or anything written by Shelah. AECs are very interesting, and you can learn a lot from Shelah, but you won't make any headway without the proper background.

Comment: By the way, Shelah's E56 is a short note called "Density is at most the spread of the square". Are you reading the book "Classification Theory for Abstract Elementary Classes Volume 1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, the ideas aer there, but it's preferable to write things in a more detailed manner. Hodges defines it using embeddings in his *Model Theory* book, but I guess it's equivalent to the following:

> Given an $L$ -structure $\mathcal N$ with domain $N$, an $L$ -structure $\mathcal M$ with domain $M$ is a substructure of $\mathcal N$ if:
>
> 1. $M\subseteq N$;
> 2. For any constant symbol $c\in L$, $c^\mathcal M=c^\mathcal N$;
> 3. For any relation symbol $R\in L$ with , $R^\mathcal M= R^\mathcal N\cap M^n$ where $n$ is the arity of $R$. This means that $$\forall (m_1,\dots,m_n)\in M^n,R^\mathcal M(m_1,\dots,m_n)\iff R^\mathcal N(m_1,\dots,m_n);$$
> 4. For any function symbol $f\in L$, $f^\mathcal M={f^\mathcal N}_{\mid M}.$

Notice that above, there's no mention of the word model whatsoever. One speaks about models when he wants structures satisfying a certain set of axioms. For example, if you take the usual language of groups $L_{gr}=\{e,\cdot,{}^{-1}\}$ where $\cdot$  is a binary function symbol, $e$ a constant symbol and ${}^{-1}$ is a unary function symbol, then if you take $\mathcal Z=(\mathbb Z,1,\times,-)$ with:

- $1=e^\mathcal Z$;
- $\times=\cdot^\mathcal Z$;
- $-=({}^{-1})^\mathcal Z$, here $-$ is interpreted as the function $x\mapsto -x$;

then $\mathcal Z$ is a perfectly fine $L_{gr}$ -structure despite it not being a group, because it doesn't satisfy the theory of groups $T_{gr}$ axiomatized by:

- $\forall x\forall y\forall z\,\, x\cdot(y\cdot z)=(x\cdot y)\cdot z$;
- $\forall x\,\, x\cdot e=x\,\,\land\,\, e\cdot x=x$;
- $\forall x\,\,x\cdot x^{-1}=e\,\,\land\,\, x^{-1}\cdot x=e$.

When we speak of a model, we mean a structure that satisfies a certain theory!

Hodges doesn't define submodel in his book, whereas Chang and Keisler define it without defining what a substructure is in their book *Model Theory*. The definition they gave corresponds to the following:

> Let $T$ be a theory and $\mathcal N$ be a model of $T$.
>
> A submodel of $\mathcal N$ is a substructure $\mathcal M$ of $\mathcal N$ which is a model of $T$.

You see in the definition above that it is intended that $\mathcal N$ is a model of $T$. If you don't specify on which theory we're working on, we may end up with a problem. For example, take the language $L=\{<\}$ and the $L$ -structure $\mathcal R=(\mathbb R,<)$. Undoubtedly  $\mathcal Z=(\mathbb Z,<)$ is an $L$ -substructure of $\mathcal R$. Is it a submodel of $\mathcal R$? Well, if you mean $\mathcal R$ as a model of the theory of total orders, then sure it is! However, if you mean $\mathcal R$ as a model of dense total orders without endpoints, then it is not because $\mathcal Z$ is not dense.

Comment: If there are no constants can $\emptyset$ be a good substructure of $\cal N$ ?

Comment: That's a pertinent question. My guess is yes, by interpreting the relations symbols and function symbols as $\emptyset$.

Comment: @user122424 The answer to this question depends on whether your definition of "structure" requires the domain to be non-empty. There is no standard convention on this point; for example, Hodges allows empty structures, while Marker does not. If empty structures are structures, and there are no constants, then every structure has a unique empty substructure.