# $ZFC^-$ and transitivity

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Why on the page 892 Shelah in his *Proper & Improper forcing* writes
$N_n$ is a countable model of $ZFC^-$ (so $\in^{N_n}$ is $\in \restriction N_n$ but $N_n$ is not necessarily transitive)

I.e. what he means by $ZFC^-$ and how the non-transitivity of $N_n$ is used?
And even, what he means by "transitive" ? Is it that $B$ is transitive iff
$A \in B \rightarrow A \subseteq B$ ?

Comment: Please do not include links to websites offering illegal downloads.

Comment: OK. But how do I communicate on the book I'm reading??

Comment: I don't know, maybe the name of the book and the edition? You know, like you'd refer to a book in a paper?

Comment: Maybe that my rest of the question after your delete is still self-explanatory?

Comment: If you search the book (especially since you probably use it in .pdf form), you can find the definition of $\sf ZFC^{-}$ on page 148. Also, your questions sort of say to me that you shouldn't be reading Shelah to begin with, if you don't have a good grasp on forcing to begin with. His book is a terrible place to learn about forcing as a first resource.

Comment: I can now see what he means by $ZFC^-$. But how he uses the possibly non-transitivity in $\in^{N_n}$ ?

Comment: It's just a countable model which is not transitive. I'm not sure what's the big issue. If you take a countable elementary submodel of any $H(\theta)$ for $\theta>\omega_1$, then $\omega_1$ being the least uncountable cardinal and thus definable without parameters, will be in that model. But by countability, it will not be a subset of the model. So you just have that. So it's just a model which is not transitive.

Comment: "Also, your questions sort of say to me that you shouldn't be reading Shelah to begin with, if you don't have a good grasp on forcing to begin with. His book is a terrible place to learn about forcing as a first resource." This is absolutely correct. It's really tempting to dive into the exciting topics right away, but **nothing** substitutes for a firm knowledge of the basics - and a text like PaIPF assumes all that, so it's really not meant to be accessible without it (and of course add to this the properties of Shelah's writing - of which PaIPF is a **actually fairly readable** example ...)

Comment: @Noah: Not without a reason. Azriel Levy wrote the introductory chapter about forcing as he took notes from a course that Saharon gave. But that's still far from enough to give the appropriate basis of knowledge for *that* kind of book, especially anything after the very basics.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I've tried to make this kind of point to this user [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038414/notion-of-submodel-relation), without any luck.